# Are LED Light strip that comes with plug ac when wire stripped?

Tags: lighting, outdoor

I have Govee weatherproof LED strips from Amazon, and I want to use my low voltage transformer 12/15v. I have no experience with installing these but would like to learn since this is low voltage and I don't think it can burn the whole house.

I have the Hampton 200w transformer and using a 14gauge low voltage wire, I will be attaching other 10w outdoor lights to it but I also have the Govee weatherproof that comes with its own as well as the Sylvania Gardenspot.

I'm wondering if I can use the same low voltage line or I need some kind of adapter, or if I can make this adapter, I found one on Amazon but 23 bucks for 1 adapter.

Comment: It will be most helpful to provide, at a minimum, pics of the items in question, even better, pics of the item's spec sheets, and maybe even links to the Amazon or mfgr listings for them.

Comment: You are cutting it very close on the wire, 200 watts is about 17 amps. Hopefully you run at least two lines from the transformer and upsize to #12. If the run were 50' #14 and the load was at the end of that you will lose a little more than 8 volts. I looked on Amazon and found a  Grovee weatherproof, it gives no technical information. I have seen similar items and they required 12V DC, transformers output AC so you may have  a compatibility problem. If we got more information such as FreeMan asked for and a rough layout with wire lengths we could give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at a few different systems from Govee and found them to run on 12 Volt AC from a wall wart. Some were 18 Watts, others were 36 Watts depending on how many lights were on the strip.

Sounds like you have a Hampton Bay 200 Watt,12 Volt,AC transformer. Technically, you could run the 12 Volt secondary from your landscape transformer, with the proper connector, into your control pad for your led strip lights provided that the total wattage from the LED strip and the other outdoor lights don't exceed the 200 Watt rating of the transformer.

If your particular set of LED lights run on 12 Volt DC from  wall wart then no, you can't do it without an addition rectifier.

Personally, I would keep them separate and use the transformer, that came with the set. It probably has better protection for the strip than the larger transformer. Plus you won't void your warranty. Since you're a newbe, follow the directions with the LED strip lighting when installing them and save the larger Hampton transformer for the landscape lights.

Comment: The 10W lights that are designed for a 200W transformer are probably (hopefully?) designed with their own overcurrent protection.  Your light strips, if they came with a wall wart, are probably not designed that way so you could in fact start a fire by connecting a transformer that is capable of pushing 17A through them if/when there is a fault.

Comment: @jay613  Most landscape fixtures do not have any over current protection... just bulbs and wire.

Comment: I was able to find a 12v rectifier at 35watts support. I was able to hook it up to both 16ft but only at 55% of brightness the other available rectifier was 65watts but it is so big I didn't bother. The transformer has 12volts output on it. I was hoping to get a 32ft but its transformer has 24v output.

Comment: @CyberNinja   You're better off keeping them separated and switching the primary side.

Answer (score 0):

My research and experiences with LED strip lights are different than @Jack.  I have not found any of the typical 16-32 ft LED strip lights that use 12V AC.  A search for Govee compatible power supply found only 12V DC wall wart.  Just check the power supply that came with your Govee LED and verify the output type.  If DC, it will have the diagram with circle and pin in the middle with + and - signs

The typical outdoor 12v Transformers for outdoor landscaping are AC, not DC.  You would need to validate if the transformer you are using is 12V AC or DC.  You would check the voltage (AC/DC) requirements of all the various light fixtures you are planning to run off the transformer to determine the type of power required, AC or DC.  Also that the total wattage is only 80% of the rating of the transformer.

If the Hampton 200w transformer is 12V AC as @Jack stated,   the Govee LED (which is DC), would require an AC/DC converter/rectifier to hook the LED strip to the 12v AC wiring.  Here is a link to an adapter that could be used.

Link to [12V AC/DCV adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08HXC4QC4) .

[image]
This is a diagram of how it is wired up. Diagram from Amazon AC/DC Adapter in the above link.

You would have to take care that your stripped wires and new connections are made watertight.  Also, the controller/receiver for the LED may not be weatherproof.

Comment: that's the rectifier I got. works fine but only at a 55% brightness for both 16ft strips, I tried to power a 32ft looks like it needs a 24v.

Comment: What is the output voltage rating on the power supply provided with your Govee LED's? Is it also dim when only one 16' strip is connected?